# Multiple collections relationship query in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables: `variants`, `jobs` and `options`. Each `variant` has many `jobs` and each `job` has many `options`.

I need to query all the `jobs` with `options.option = 'tbd'` belonging to a certain `variant`.

For example I have `variant.id=5`, then the query should be something like:

`SELECT jobs.name FROM jobs LEFT JOIN options ON jobs.id = options.job_id WHERE options.option = 'tbd' AND jobs.variant_id = 5`

How can I got this in Eloquent? `Variant::find(5)->jobs->has('options.option','=','tbd')` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
Variant::find(5)->jobs()->whereHas('options',function($q) {
                    $q->where('option','tbd');
                });
```

Comment: You can try with debugbar

Comment: BadMethodCallException with message 'Method whereHas does not exist.'

Comment: @AlexandruAntochi use `...->jobs()->whereHas(...`